# How can I use JDate to work with UK times to include BST and GMT?

Tags: date, jdate, timezone

In the UK, we have GMT (Greenwhich Mean Time) for half the year and then we put the clocks forward by an hour to BST (British Summer Time) for the other half of the year.

How can I handle this issue within Joomla?  Currently all of my modified dates in my component are incorrect by an hour.  I know Joomla! bases it on the server time, so I guess I could speak to my host.

Is there a way to handle this otherwise?

In response to Hugh's comment, my Joomla configuration settings are set to London, and it has always been, so I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: You can set the timezone in your .htaccess file. For details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33157095

Comment: Eoin, have you set the timezone of your website in Joomla's global configuration under 'server' settings? By default you will have UTC which would explain the results you are getting.

Comment: `use Joomla\CMS\Date\Date;` then `$date = new Date('now', 'Europe/London');`. Does that work?

Comment: But it's set in the global config.  Or does that not matter because the server could be wrong?  In which case is it simply a fact of telling the host to fix this stuff?

Comment: @Lodder no still not working

Comment: Joomla always stores the date/DateTime in UTC. It uses the selected timezone while displaying the dates. Which code are you using to display the dates? Are you having the same problem also in core Joomla Articles?

Comment: In addition to Jumbo:  JDate always saves a UTC date and converts it automatically. So you need to use JDate. Depending on the Joomla settings, it is converted to the time zone of the user or the server.
These commands help me:
`JHtml::_('date', $myDate)` will output an UTC date in the user's timezone automatically.
`JHtml::_('calender', $myDate ...)` won't convert the date to the user's timezone 
If you use `JForm calender time` you can use filter: `SERVER_UTC` or `USER_UTC` that will handle the timezone calculations for you: https://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of doing this then, it does depend a lot on how the server is setup, but if you have access to the .htaccess file in your public_html folder (where Joomla is installed) you could add the following line:

```
php_value date.timezone 'Europe/London'
```

I would recommend creating a file called phpinfo.php (delete it afterwards)
which contains

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

If you search this file for date.timezone it will tell you what the local and server values are.

Comment: It looks like you haven't yet taken our [tour], Hugh.  Stack Exchange sites are not conversational forums, the posts on each page are either the original poster's question or a question-resolving answer.  If you have questions to pose to the asker or relevant insights which will be helpful to the asker/researchers, these should be written as comments under the question. You do not yet have the privilege to comment, so I am going to convert your other _answer_ to be a comment under the question because it asks for clarification and does not resolve the question.

Comment: Thanks @hugh and welcome to JSE.  I have spoken to my host and the date/time is correct, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Nope, still not working with `php_value` either

Comment: PHP info says `Default timezone  Europe/London `

Comment: Although I was about to point out that most of this stuff is available in Joomla system info without the need for PHP info.  BUT when I did I spotted.  `Default timezone  UTC` so it's Joomla not server related.